# need some advice with "increment" in "jedis"

Tags: java, redis, jedis

*Tested with jedis 2.6.1 and 2.6.2.*

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("mykey", "myhashkey", 1);

127.0.0.1:6379> hkeys "mykey"
1) "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\tmyhashkey"

127.0.0.1:6379> hget "mykey" "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\tmyhashkey"
"\xac\xed\x00\x05sr\x00\x11java.lang.Integer\x12\xe2\xa0\xa4\xf7\x81\x878\x02\x00\x01I\x00\x05valuexr\x00\x10java.lang.Number\x86\xac\x95\x1d\x0b\x94\xe0\x8b\x02\x00\x00xp\x00\x00\x00\x01"
```

Then I'm trying to increment my value

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().increment("mykey", "myhashkey", 1);
```

but I got the following problem:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR hash value is not an integer; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR hash value is not an integer
```

When I'm doing

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().increment("mykey", "myhashkey1", 1);
```

and field is not present in redis than it works perfect.

Any advice?

Comment: So have you tried the raw `hset` as in my answer ? I have found a way to disable serialization, with `redisTemplate.enableDefaultSerializer = false;`, but that is not a decent solution nevertheless.

Comment: @Niloct no, i didn't tried yet. but i agree with you that the problem is serialisation.

Answer (score 1):

After you do `redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("mykey", "myhashkey", 1);` from `hget` result you can see that you result is serial by default JDK serializer. If you want to save hash as your origin value you should use `StringRedisSerializer` as serial method.

For example you should configure `redisTemplate` part in xml as follow:

```
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
<property name="keySerializer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"></bean>
</property>
<property name="hashKeySerializer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer" />
</property>
<property name="hashValueSerializer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer" />
</property>
```

Then if you do `redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("mykey", "myhashkey", 1)`, and then do `redisTemplate.opsForHash().increment("mykey", "myhashkey1", 1);`, it works. Because using `StringRedisSerializer`, it saves 1 into `"1"`, and default JDK Serializer would save 1 to serial such as `"\xac\xed\x00\x0"`.

Comment: Thanks for your revision on this anwser, there were truly many format errors, best wishes @Hugo

Comment: use StringRedisSerializer as serial method ,is working

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is in your post!

```
hget "mykey" "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\tmyhashkey"
```

The value stored in your hash's key `\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\tmyhashkey` is not an integer, it's

> "\xac\xed\x00\x05sr\x00\x11java.lang.Integer\x12\xe2\xa0\xa4\xf7\x81\x878\x02\x00\x01I\x00\x05valuexr\x00\x10java.lang.Number\x86\xac\x95\x1d\x0b\x94\xe0\x8b\x02\x00\x00xp\x00\x00\x00\x01"

(it seems a serialization of a java object).

If you `hset mykey \xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\tmyhashkey 1`, and then you issue an increment, it should work.

I still have to study how your client works, I've only dealed with PHPRedis which is awesome. Let's see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

set hash key and value serializer like this:

```
redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

and put value like this:

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().increment("mykey", "myhashkey", "1");
```